# Will editting a Magento database directly (i.e. with phpmyadmin) 'harm' the installation?

Tags: database, csv, magento

I want to change all of the SKU's I've setup on a Magento installation slightly so they match to the ones set on our stock-controlling system. I'd like to make the changes in an excel spreadsheet.

So, if I were to export the catalog_product_entity table as a CSV from phpmyadmin, make my changes, save as a CSV and import via phpmyadmin - would Magento kick up a fuss or just display the changes I made?

Thanks.

Comment: This heavily depends on the exact nature of the changes you're about to make. If the SKU is used as a reference to another table, you will break the data this way. If not, it may work... Only someone with a good foundational knowledge of Magento can tell.

Comment: Hence asking here. :-) I THINK Magento uses product ID's for inter-table relations rather than the SKU - or at least it would make sense for this exact reason (and a whole load of other reasons). I just wondered if there were any other issues that may be caused that more Magento-savvy users could comment on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has worked for me in the past. I was a bit scared too, so I did a big column in OOO with 'CONCATENATE 'UPDATE blah SET `sku` = ', A1, ' WHERE `sku` = ', B1;' type of in the spreadsheet and updated the table rather than reimport it. I also turned off any cron tasks just in case.

Now I did come a cropper with this technique. I updated some products (new versions of old ones) and ended up with duplicate skus. Yikes! Anyway, so long as you avoid duplicate skus then you will find that Magento is surprisingly robust when it comes to mysql sku renaming. Good luck and have fun!

Comment: Thanks. I'll probably do that too. :-)